# Is there a way to force PostgreSQL to use the UTF-7 encoding for the connection?

Tags: postgresql, unicode

I have a PostgreSQL database which uses an arcane text encoding, and I can't change that. Is there a way tostore text in UTF-7 transparently (for the informed client) so that the database engine doesn't complain that it cannot convert Unicode characters, but the client can still use any Unicode characters out there? I can do this conversion manually, but I hope there is a way to do it without manual conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SQL_ASCII`, which tells the database to pass the bytes for text transparently without any validation or conversion.

This is usually a terrible idea that leads to a horrid mix of incompatible and mismatched text encodings in a DB, with some apps inserting UTF-8, others latin-1, etc. It is an option if you need to work with an encoding that the database cannot actually understand, though.

Your alternative would be to add support for utf-7 to PostgreSQL. This might not be too difficult as all the encoding handling is pretty well abstracted.

Comment: I can't change the database encoding, and I don't control the database server. Is it possible to use SQL_ASCII as the client encoding if the server encoding is something else?

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko If the server encoding is fixed, your only option would be to store data as `bytea` or something like base64 `text` and do your encoding/decoding client side. That'll be painful.